# SimpleMemberShip WebSecurity Login after registration for once

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

My web application required user after registered got logged in for once, and if user logout he must activate his account by a ConfirmationToken. I found that the `requireConfirmationToken:false` lets you login after registration but you will loose the activation, and vise versa.

```
bool isLoggedIn = WebSecurity.Login(registerModel.Username, registerModel.Password);

// isLoggedIn false if requireConfirmationToken:true & true if requireConfirmationToken:false
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This is rather easy to do, you simply assume the user is valid if they successfully register and issue a FormsAuthentication ticket for them with a non-persistent cookie.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetCookie(username, false);
```

This will make them authenticated after they are registered (well, after the next page refresh), until they close their browser or log out.  Afterwards, logging in will fail until they activate their account.

Comment: This is an ideal solution for the scenario you described.

Answer (score 0):

If you set requireConfirmationToken to true you have to use email confirmation to have the user confirm that they have provided a valid email address. During the process of email confirmation you call the [WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569286%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method. Until the account is confirmed the login will fail every time.  You can [read more about setting up email confirmation here](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/02/adding-email-confirmation-to.html).

Comment: Kevin, is there any way to cancel confirmation, presently conforming the user registration using 'WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount' method, i need to cancel/ disable user account?

Comment: What do you mean by "cancel confirmation"? Are you using confirmation and now you want to set the user to confirmed when you do not have the token?  Please explain.